# Untouched Website Since September -- Now Throws INDEX_SIZE_ERROR DOM Exception 1

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

My website shows a Google Map with an average of about 20-30 markers and polylines. All the markers and polylines update every few seconds using a JavaScript timer that calls into some ASP.Net code to get new coordinates for all the markers.

This website worked perfectly last September when it built and demoed. It was left on for days at a time. At the end of the month, the website was figuratively put up on the shelf and not used anymore.

A new demo just popped up, so I opened up the website this week, 6 months later. The website is now drawing some of the polylines, and some of the markers, but not nearly all of them. The website also throws "INDEX_SIZE_ERR: DOM Exception 1" messages when it tries to redraw.

My server and code didn't change at all, so it feels like a Google Maps API issue.

Does anybody have any ideas for what happened?

Comment: a link to the website would be helpful

Comment: and the code that exhibits the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Google Maps API has been updated a couple of times since last September.

[see the description of versioning in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/basics#Versioning)

[or the ChangeLog for changes](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/wiki/JavascriptMapsAPIv3Changelog)

Comment: That was exactly the problem. I was using google.maps.MarkerImage, which looks it was deprecated during my period of inactivity. Thanks!